# Converting SQL Date to String

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I am working in Coldfusion and MS-SQL.

I have a query that delivers a list of possible dates in a Query Struct. I want to convert these dates to their corresponding String representations.

Must I loop over the query and convert each Sql/Coldfusion date to its String representation?

Comment: What's a "Query Struct"? There are queries and there are structs. They're different.

Comment: Why do you need to convert them? ColdFusion is typeless. You can do string manipulation against a variables containing a date without any sort of conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-- < >: place holders that require programmer input
-- n  : the length of the style format

SELECT CONVERT(<tbl>.<field>, <style code>) AS DateString FROM <tbl>

SELECT CAST(CONVERT(<tbl>.<field>, <style code>) AS varchar(<n>)) As DateString
FROM   <tbl>
```

---

#### Date Styles

```
Style Code  Format                       Example                   Style
0 or 100    mon dd yyyy hh:mmAM          Mar 8 2011 9:00PM         Default. Equivalent to not specifying a style code.
1           mm/dd/yy                     03/23/11                  USA date.
2           yy.mm.dd                     11.03.23                  ANSI date.
3           dd/mm/yy                     23/03/11                  UK / French date.
4           dd.mm.yy                     23.03.11                  German date.
5           dd-mm-yy                     23-03-11                  Italian date.
6           dd mmm yy                    23 Mar 11                 Abbreviated month.
7           mmm dd, yy                   Mar 23, 11                Abbreviated month.
8 or 108    HH:mm:ss                     21:00:00                  24 hour time.
9 or 109    mon dd yyyy hh:mm:ss:fffAM   Mar 8 2011 9:00:00:000PM  Default formatting with seconds and milliseconds appended.
10          mm-dd-yy                     03-23-11                  USA date with hyphen Mararators.
11          yy/mm/dd                     11/03/23                  Japanese date.
12          yymmdd                       110323                    ISO date.
13 or 113   dd mon yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff     23 Mar 2011 21:00:00:000  European default with seconds and milliseconds.
14 or 114   HH:mm:ss:fff                 21:00:00:000              24 hour time with milliseconds.
20 or 120   yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss          2011-03-23 21:00:00       ODBC canonical date and time.
21 or 121   yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.fff      2011-03-23 21:00:00.000   ODBC canonical date and time with milliseconds.
101         mm/dd/yyyy                   03/23/2011                USA date with century.
102         yyyy.mm.dd                   2011/03/23                ANSI date with century.
103         dd/mm/yyyy                   23/03/2011                UK / French date with century.
104         dd.mm.yyyy                   23.03.2011                German date with century.
105         dd-mm-yyyy                   23-03-2011                Italian date with century.
106         dd mmm yyyy                  23 Mar 2011               Abbreviated month with century.
107         mmm dd, yyyy                 Mar 23, 2011              Abbreviated month with century.
110         mm-dd-yyyy                   03-23-2011                USA date with hyphen Mararators and century.
111         yyyy/mm/dd                   2011/03/23                Japanese date with century.
112         yyyymmdd                     20110323                  ISO date with century.
126         yyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss           2011-03-23T21:00:00       ISO8601, for use in XML.
```

---

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

**Using CAST then CONVERT**

```
SELECT 
   GETDATE() AS UnconvertedDateTime,
   CAST(GETDATE() AS nvarchar(30)) AS UsingCast,
   CONVERT(nvarchar(30), GETDATE(), 126) AS UsingConvertTo_ISO8601  ;
GO

-- Outputs:
--   UnconvertedDateTime      UsingCast            UsingConvertTo_ISO8601
--   -----------------------  -------------------  ------------------------------
--   2006-04-18 09:58:04.570  Apr 18 2006 9:58AM   2006-04-18T09:58:04.570
--
--   (1 row(s) affected)
```

**Using CONVERT then CAST**

```
SELECT 
   '2006-04-25T15:50:59.997' AS UnconvertedText,
   CAST('2006-04-25T15:50:59.997' AS datetime) AS UsingCast,
   CONVERT(datetime, '2006-04-25T15:50:59.997', 126) AS UsingConvertFrom_ISO8601 ;
GO


-- Outputs:
--   UnconvertedText          UsingCast                UsingConvertTo_ISO8601
--   -----------------------  -------------------      ------------------------------
--   2006-04-25T15:50:59.997  2006-04-25 15:50:59.997  2006-04-25 15:50:59.997
--
--   (1 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do it on the server.

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(datetime, [tableName].DateField, 1) as varchar(8)) As DateString,
[tableName].DateField As DateField
FROM [tableName]
```

This returns a date string WITHOUT century (mm/dd/yy).

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(datetime, [tableName].DateField, 101) as varchar(10)) As DateString,
[tableName].DateField As DateField
FROM [tableName]
```

This returns a date string WITH century (mm/dd/yyyy).

For more information, check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Comment: + 1 this is definitely the most efficient. Unless the questioner provides additional detail don't think there's anything else to see here.

Comment: Actually I also need the Coldfusion/SQL Dates in my Script!

Comment: @user160820, you can just alias the field, so you can do something like SELECT DateField, CAST(... DateField...) AS DateString FROM myTable. That way you have both the original value, and your string representation in the query.